# Optimizing form for bulk book orders with quantity?

Tags: forms, order

I am creating a form where a user can quickly copy and paste multiple book ISBNS. My question is how should I allow the user to specify quantity for each book?

My suggestion is space delimited after each ISBN for the quantity. I am afraid that this method might be error prone. Most users will extract the data from excel sheets.

I hope my question isn't too vague.

[image: a busy cat]

[1] https://i.stack.imgur.com/P47mF.jpg "Order Form"

Comment: how many books may user order at a time? 3, 5, 10, 20, more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Most users will extract the data from excel sheets.

So make them happy and do the magic!

Name this form as a "Search books". And add detailed instruction how to copy from Excel.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnMmxn.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Once Find button is pressed, you refine data and show it in a editable way:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIojBD.png)</sup>